# Xcode 8, TableView is not shown because of leading and trailing constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, xcode8

since i updated to Xcode 8 i have a problem with my storyboard and no clue how to fix it.

In my ViewController i have a separate View with a TableView inside. This second View has trailing, leading and top constraints and is shown. But if i add leading and trailing constraints to the TableView, so that the View is stretched with the display width, the tableView isn't appearing when i start the app.

With Xcode 7 everything was working fine that way. What could it be?

Here is a Screenshot showing the View with the TableView.
[image]

And here you see the constraints
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UITableView` must have top and height/bottom constraints

Comment: You are right, when i add top and bottom constraints i see the tableView. But the Cell is still missing and i can't add constraints to the cell. Do you have a tip for that problem, too?

Comment: If you add a bottom constraint to your `UITableView` then you must add a height constraint to it's super view.

Comment: Thank you @J. Koush, now i get my tableView like before.